# Distributing R scripts to non-coders

Tags: r, software-distribution

I work as the single data scientist in a company, and I have around 15 or so functions that generates an Excel sheet with various information in - and this number will increase in the future. These sheets are used by relatively many people in the company, but only I can run them, since none of them knows R, and it is not really an option to just teach them how to run functions, since many of them have quite limited IT skills.

For the sake of the example, lets assume we have a script as:

```
library(openxlsx)
Example_function <- function(foo){
    wb <- createWorkbook()
    addWorksheet(wb, "Sheet1")
    writeData(wb, "Sheet1", bar)
    saveWorkbook(wb, "bar.xlsx")
}
```

My idea was to have some kind og drag and drop system, or something clickable with the functions and arguments, that they want to use. I have not been able to find such a software, that can do this in a satisfying way. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Did you have a look at Shiny?

Comment: I did yes, and that could work, but doesnt shiny just display the result from the parameter I choose? I have functions with date arguments, and when we have data from several years, that will not be optimal.

Comment: With shiny, you could design an interface to which they could upload a file, R does the analysis, and then they can download the result, for example.

Comment: Oh, I did not know that was possible with shiny. That could work!

Comment: You can also make your R scripts into batch files so the user just double clicks a file and then the function is run.  But this usually means the customization is pretty static.  It also does require that the user has R installed on their computer, as will be the case with most local solutions. I also use shiny in my org and you can package apps with google chrome portable and R portable (google it).  But admittedly it's a little cumbersome.

Comment: @Balter what you are referring to in the last part of your comment, is this what is described here?
https://www.r-bloggers.com/deploying-desktop-apps-with-r/

Comment: Google *Shiny Gallery* to see examples of what is possible.

Comment: @Acarbalacar yep you got it.  I used that guide and maybe another similar to it.  I had to fiddle with a few things to get it to work but now I deploy a lot of my applications in a similar way.  Free advice, once you get it working, it might be wise to build in a self updating feature if you plan to make updates in the future.  Otherwise you need to distribute updates to all users manually.  Also be mindful of the version of R and packages you've deployed with.  PS - you can always pay for shinyapps.io or one of the Rstudio server options and life is MUCH easier.  Hope this helps!

Comment: @Balter Thank you. I was just about to ask about what you did server wise, but you beat me to it! And yes, I was also planning to make it self updating in some way, when new data comes in. If you could make an answer with the things you have mentioned here in the comments, I will happily accept it.